# lazy loading for recursive vue components

Tags: recursion, vuejs2, vue-component, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

In *Vue2*, I'm creating a component in a tree-shape, i.e it calls itself recursively.
Each recursive component requires some computation, and if there's a big data passed to the root instance, the whole site gets stuck for few seconds until the computation is done..

I thought of using a lazy loading of the recursive component.
The user doesn't open any when the site loads, and there's no reason for them to render all at once.

According to the *Vue Guide*, one should do:

```js
components: {
  myComponent: () => import("./pathToComponent/myComponent.vue")
}
```

The problem is that recursive component doesn't import itself, but using name:

```js
export default {
  name: "myComponent",
  data() {
    return {...}
  }
  ...
}
```

How do I use dynamic-import (or lazy-loading) in this situation?

Comment: I would limit it by using `v-if`'s. "The user doesn't open any when the site loads..", so use v-if on the un-needed markup that is "closed"